# Store key-less JSON to Realm using Retrofit

Tags: android, realm, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to save the following JSON from an online API directly to Realm using Retrofit. I am struggling to define the model because there are no keys and the values are dynamic.

JSON:

```
{
  "Plants": {
    "Green": [
      "Ascia",
      "Musca Arabica"
      ...
    ],
    "Yellow": [
      "Campona",
      "Zirata",
      ...
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this even doable? I know I can use a `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>`, but makeing the Realm model is causing me trouble.

Comment: Why not create your own decorator class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten it completely.

```
public class Data extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey 
    private String typeCategoryName; // "Plants_Green_Ascia"

    @Index
    private String type; // "Plants"
    @Index
    private String category; // "Green"

    private String name; // "Ascia"
}
```

Then you could query it like

```
RealmResults<Data> data = realm.where(Data.class)
                            .equalTo("type", "Plants")
                            .equalTo("category", "Green")
                            .findAll();
```